# Selenium WebDriver can't find element by @FindBy annotation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, annotations, findby

I want to find this element

```
driver.findElement(By.className("name")).findElement(By.tagName("a"));
```

is there way to use `@FindBy` annotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. Selenium supports both `@FindBys` and `@FindAll` which adds finer tuning for page objects.

For chained element look-up, (which is what you're doing, a look-up inside a look-up), you'll want `@FindBys`.

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(className = "name"), @FindBy(tagName= "a")})
private WebElement element;
```

Further reading on [FindBys](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBys.html) and [FindAll](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindAll.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer, i solved the problem. luv you ♡

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for an "a" tag inside an element with the "name" class, try combining them via XPath or CSS selectors:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class = 'name']/a")
private WebElement nameLink;
```

or

```
@FindBy(css = ".name > a")
private WebElement nameLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

I several test `FindBys` annotation in selenium but sometime when use 
`TageName` and `Name` it's not correctly work!!.

ofter Find `List<WebElement>` use `driver.findElement(By.name("...."))` to do filter.